# I cannot build localy my android app - New to phonegap

Tags: java, node.js, ant, cordova

I am very new to phonegap. I have follow any step to install phonegap and now I am faced with a problem I cannot determine the solution.

I am starting by executing the commands:

```
phonegap create hello
cd hello
```

and then I am executing the following command and I am getting the result you can read:

```
E:\Web Development Projects\dch\p\phonegap.dch\hello>phonegap local build android
phonegap  adding the Android platform...

C:\Users\MyNAme\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\cordova\src\metadata\android_parser.js:35
    throw new Error('The provided path "' + project + '" is not an Android
          ^
Error: The provided path "E:\Web Development Projects\dch\p\phonegap.dch\hello\platforms\android" is not an Android project.
at Object.android_parser (C:\Users\MyNAme\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\cordova\src\metadata\android_parser.js:35:15)
at C:\Users\MyNAme\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\cordova\src\prepare.js:67:23
at Array.map (native)
at Object.prepare (C:\Users\MyNAme\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\cordova\src\prepare.js:65:30)
at C:\Users\MyNAme\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\cordova\src\platform.js:234:47
at C:\Users\MyNAme\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\shelljs\shell.js:1707:7
at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:577:7)
at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:97:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:677:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:744:5)
```

In my system I have properly installed the following:

```
Node.js
jre7
jdk1.7.0_45
Android SDK
Ant
```

and are registered all the appropriate system path variable that pointing to the required folders to run the phonegap.

Is there any solution to this problem ?

**UPDATE 1**

I try to find out what's wrong, and I found that the `C:\Users\MyNAme\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\cordova\src\metadata\android_parser.js` is looking for a file named `AndroidManifest.xml` under the path `E:\Web Development Projects\dch\p\phonegap.dch\hello\platforms\android`.

Unfortunatelly I don't have any folder named android under my platforms folde of my app, and thus I don't even have the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

So, the qeustion is, did I meased any step ? :?

**UPDATE 2**

I just run the following command as described by the MBilau:

```
phonegap -d local platform add android
```

and I got the following output:

```
error 'platform' is not a node C:\User\MyName\AppData\Raoming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\bing\phonegap.js command. See 'node C:\User\MyName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\bin\phonegap.js help'
```

Is there anybody who can help ? :?

Comment: The problem might be that the path has a space in it. Windows does not deal very well with spaces. Instead of `E:\Web Development Projects\dch\....` try to rename it to `E:\WebDevelopmentProjects\dch\...` and see if that works.

Comment: I just try to build an application in path without spaces. Still the same problem :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you run `phonegap local build` I think you need to run `phonegap local platform add android`, which will add `/android/` folder to your `/platforms/` directory. It will also pull in all of the needed files to create an Android app, like the Manifest file.

Comment: I have try the command you describe above, but not luck. More specific, this command does not produce the required folders, but also does not make any output in my CLI. Thanks anyway :) I have up vote you for your try :)

Comment: You can add `-d` to any command with the CLI to get output, like `phonegap -d local build`